# Save background image url on reload

Tags: html, jquery, css

So I have this HTML + CSS + jQuery code:

```css
#header{
  background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/oKe8JBR.png');
  background-repeat:no-repeat ;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  width:500px;
  height:500px;

}

.test{
    background: url('https://i.imgur.com/oKe8JBR.png');
    border: 0;
    padding: 37px;
    background-size: cover;
    padding-left: 70px;
}

.test2{
    background: url('https://i.imgur.com/UZhKDMu.png');
    border: 0;
   padding: 37px;
    background-size: cover;
    padding-left: 70px;
}

.test3{
    background: url('https://i.pinimg.com/originals/a0/df/19/a0df19b8781bca3f2356013600131728.jpg');
    border: 0;
    padding: 37px;
    background-size: cover;
    padding-left: 70px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body><header id="header"></header>
        <button class="test"></button>
        <button class="test2"></button>
        <button class="test3"></button>
        
        <script>
            $('.test').click(function()
          {
            $('#header').css("background", "url(https://i.imgur.com/oKe8JBR.png)");
            $('#header').css("background-position-y", "13.2%");
          });
            
            $('.test2').click(function()
          {
            $('#header').css("background", "url(https://i.imgur.com/UZhKDMu.png)");
            $('#header').css("background-position-y", "40%");
            $('#header').css("background-size", "cover"); 
          });
          
           $('.test3').click(function()
          {
            $('#header').css("background", "url(https://i.pinimg.com/originals/a0/df/19/a0df19b8781bca3f2356013600131728.jpg)");
          });
          
          </script>
          
        </body>
```

I'm trying to do a header image changer. The codes works fine but I want the images to be saved into a localSession or even into cookies and on document.load to show the background-image that I picked last time.

For example: If I choose image with class .test2, on page reload it to be loaded.

Comment: I am a newbie into JavaSript, I don't really know how to deal with it

Comment: Sure, we all start somewhere, but SO is not the place to ask this type of question. Use Google to search for using JS to add to localStorage or a cookie. Here's one tutorial: https://www.taniarascia.com/how-to-use-local-storage-with-javascript/